# Android Httppost and php, messy encoding

Tags: php, android, encoding, http-post, utf

I have the following problem. I'm trying to send data using httppost in Android (my code looks like this http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient). The server using php to get data, here is code:

```
<?php
$fileContents = $_POST["xml"];
$fileHandle = fopen("test.xml", 'w') or die("can't create file");
fprintf($fileHandle, "%s", $fileContents);
fclose($fileHandle);
?>
```

It works fine, except non ascii characters are messy in file. When I used php script to send data - all non ascii characters were shown exactly as it needed. What should I do?

Comment: any characters in particular?

Comment: The part of xml code, which is messy: <testName>%%%%%%</testName> (where % - some unprintable characters), must be <testName>география</testName>

Comment: the part that does the urlencodedformentity might be causing the problem...I am pretty sure that is more intended for http get requests...I have to go and look up a couple things, sec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick instead of the urlencodingformentity stuff:
http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=735

I googled 'java post utf8' to help find this potential solution, in case you need to find more details. :)

Comment: p.s.  I like your username :P

Answer (score 0):

You can set ut8 in posted data and also in PHP(and in database too if you want to insert data).
 We don't have your code to see what and how you are posting things to comment specifically, but UTF8 is the way to go